# How to convert serialized byte array back to its text form

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, arrays, encode

I have a text that is a property of an object.The object gets XmlSerialized and after that there is an element in the XML call Text that represents the text from the object.I am wondering how to turn it back to string.

**THE TYPE OF SERIALIZATION**: `XmlSerializer serizlizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Act));`

**THE PROPERTY IN THE CLASS** :

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private byte[] ActTextField;
```

In the xml file it looks something like that:

`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`

I can not even suppose what is its encoding and how to decode it.I tried to read it into byte array but it didn't actualy work after applying few decodings **Encode.UTF8 , Encode.ASCII,**

Comment: Could you provide some more details about the class involved and how you're serializing? This really doesn't look like encoded *text* data at all. It looks like base64-encoded binary data which is itself *not* just text.

Comment: "In the xml file it looks something like that:" - is that the **actual** data? or is it *illustrative* (but fake) data?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like Base64 to me - just use

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Text);
```

It's odd that it's using base64 at all if this is really a *text* property though. I'd expect just the text.

To convert that binary data back to text you would need to know which encoding was used to convert it to the binary data to start with - and UTF-8 is the most likely - but all the repeated `AAAAA...` parts in there make this look pretty unlike text, to be honest.

EDIT: Now that we've seen the field declaration, we can see that it was a `byte[]` to start with, so that makes sense for it to be encoded in this way. Judging by comments, it sounds like it's actually a Word file - at which point extracting the text is a very separate problem.

Comment: How am I supposed to assign it to a string after that ?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: As I said, it doesn't look like the kind of data which really started off as a string. All those `AAAA` bits would end up as 00 bytes, which would be unusual in text. Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik in the general-case: "decode it with the `Encoding` that it was encoded with" - but that *doesn't look like it is encoded text*

Comment: Me myself don't know much about the class.I just have it but how the text is being assigned to and object I don't really know.The file comes from a Service reference so I am not very clear with the way the text is being assigned to a particular object.I will update my question with all the information that I have for the class.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: Well we're not going to be able to help you without more information about what the data is actually meant to represent - but it's pretty clear that it's either *not* just text, or it's very unusual text. I suggest you make further enquiries with whatever the data source is.

Comment: I will definately do some researches! This is not just a plain text , I am pretty much sure that it has formatting included.That is why there might be weird symbols inside the string that I posted.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: Then it sounds like it's really binary data to start with. A string simply doesn't have any formatting associated with it. Perhaps it's actually a Word document or a PDF?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Exactly!It is not simple plain text serialized.

Comment: Now I even realised that this is one whole file serialized.It is not just plain text.Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: Right - at that point, it's easy: just convert the base64 to binary as shown in the answer, and save that as a file (or whatever you want to do with it).

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you think that I could load it as MS Word and exrtact its text content? I know that I can to that with the Microsoft.Office.Interop but it is sooo slooow.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: You'd need to either use interop or a third-party library. I suggest you look for other questions about that - it's definitely off-topic for *this* question.